# Polling FTP server uses too many ports

Tags: ftp, ports

I have an application that is monitoring 100 files on an ftp
files on the ftp can change frequently
If I detect a change in the file I download the file

Someone in the IT department is saying that I am using too many ports to do this.
He is running netstat and seeing many ports in a TIME_WAIT state that originate from the computer my application is running.

Isn't this how FTP works though? One port per transfer in the ephemeral range?

Comment: Passive or active mode? Where is the admin running the `netstat` on the server or client machine?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in general, that's how FTP works.

For each transfer a new port is assigned. Once a transfer completes the port switches to the `TIME_WAIT` state for a system-defined time.

Comment: Should we expect any performance issue in this? If so whats the solution to address it?